# Hibernate boolean field mapping issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, boolean

There is a boolean field in Entity :

```
@Column(name = "FREEFLAG", columnDefinition = "NUMBER(0,1) default 0", nullable = false)    
public boolean getFreeflag() {
   return freeflag;
}
```

database - Oracle, field FREEFLAG - NUMBER(0,1)

I try to get object from db with Hibernate, but if the field in db is null i got a exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type
```

Why default value doesn't work ?
How I can resolve this problem on server side? I have to have 0 or 1 value in db.

I got the solution - [Default value not working in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983230/default-value-not-working-in-hibernate). But I still have to modify database. I have added DDL - alter table client modify freeflag default 0 not null
DML - update client set freeflag = 0 where freeflag is null; commit

Comment: Is there data already in the database? The default in the database default on _storing_ the entity, not the Java default on loading.

Comment: Yes, free flag in db is null.I can have null value in db, I don't have to change db settings. Can I set default value when i get value from db ?

Comment: You can edit the setter to set `false` if `null` is sent - but this is a hack. The setter would need to be `Boolean` rather than `boolean`.

Comment: This is a hack. I dont have to change getter or setter

Comment: This is ORM - you are mapping the state of the DB to your POJOs. If the database allows `NULL` then you will have to allow `null` in your POJO too.

Comment: Hm.. It's clear, I thought that I can set default value to field on server side. Thanks Boris

Comment: Same problem is solved [here][1] in stackoverflow check for it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13594108/3828557

Comment: Muhammad sorry, but I have Oracle DB with appropriate consequences

Comment: columnDefinition = "NUMBER(0,1) default '0'" can you try with this single quote '0' syntax.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, doesn't matter, nothing happened.
Actually columnDefinition doesn't work.

Comment: I GOT THE SOLUTION - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983230/default-value-not-working-in-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments you have said that your database allow null values for this column. The `columnDefinition` attribute is used by JPA Provider during schema generation process, so I can assume that you have not generated schema after you added `columnDefinition` attribute (nor `nullable=false`). Hints in `columnDefinition` which set default value were not applied to database, so it's nothing strange that you don't have this column defaulted.

Another way you can make it work is creating custom `Converter` for this field, which will save values in the way you need. More informations about converters implementation available [here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html).

Answer (score 0):

The columnDefinition is database dependent and hence might cause issues sometimes. What I got from searching on net is that it works sometimes but doesnt work in some cases. An alternative is to use the prePersist method technique described in below link:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/450124/ORM/databases/entity-Boolean-field-default

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, but this is hack I think. Actually I can add logic to my getter :
@Column(name = "FREEFLAG",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    public Boolean getFreeflag() {
 if (freeFlag == null) return false;    
return freeflag;
 }

but I dont like this approach.